# What is this fictional element named Redstone and which comic does it come from?

Tags: story-identification

Someone showed me this image:

[image: The Periodic Table of Fictional Elements]

In particular, they noted the comic book element redstone, Rs. the format states it is created by HA.

I did a bit of searching, checking Wikipedia, and I'm pretty stumped by what this element called redstone is or where it is from. Of course I know redstone from Minecraft, but this is apparently distinct, since it's in the comic book section.

Who or what is HA, and what is this version of redstone?

Comment: For people who might be searching like me. the Redstone _Rs_ element is at the bottom row, second green square, near the _Su_

Comment: I tried to clarify the title but I'm not entirely sure I was able to keep the original meaning/intent. Feel free to rollback if you believe my edit changed it.

Comment: Clown's(Cw) an element?!?!?

Comment: @shanu At the risk of flooding the site with "what fictional element is this" questions, you could always ask a separate question about what "Clown" is.

Comment: @F1Krazy Chances are it _might_ be marked as dupe of this one, since I mentioned in the answer below how to learn more about every elements in the picture. But yeah, I agree, I almost answered in the comment until I saw yours.

Comment: What is fictional about Promethium? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promethium

Comment: Minecraft uses a lot of redstone.

Comment: @AlexanderKlauer Same goes for Carbonite(C) on the right, just below Be: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonite_(ion)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [this website](https://mightymega.com/2013/08/28/interactive-periodic-table-of-fictional-elements/), there used to be an interactive version of that fictional periodic table:

http://www.fictionalmaterials.com/

However, that link is no longer functional because the site died. But we can access it through [the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20111209015335/http://www.fictionalmaterials.com/). The page is blank, but upon checking its source code, we can download the following Flash content, which is the interactive periodic table: [periodiekklein.swf](https://web.archive.org/web/20111209015335/http://www.fictionalmaterials.com/periodiekklein.swf).

By using a software to run the Flash content, we can see the following:

[image: An interactive version of the fictional periodic table, which allows us to get more information by moving the mouse over a square.]

> **Name:** Red Stone
> **Source:** Fullmetal Alchemist - Hiromu Arakawa
> **Specifications:** Reddish stone. Ampifies the transmutation power of alchemists. Made with Red Water, a high-toxic liquid.

The Red Stone is also called the [Philosopher's Stone](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone) in the manga [Fullmetal Alchemist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullmetal_Alchemist); although in this particular case, since Red Water is mentioned, it is most likely a reference to [another kind of Red Stone from the 2003 anime](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/Philosopher%27s_Stone#Red_Stone), which is distinct from the Philosopher's Stone. *HA* is the author [Hiromu Arakawa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiromu_Arakawa).

If you want to learn more about the other elements, you can download the file and run it either with a standalone Flash Player, or any browser based Flash Player (e.g. Ruffle for example).

Comment: Brilliant detective work!

Comment: For what it's worth, I initially tried to find _any_ comic book publisher whose name might be _HA_. In the end, I pasted the question's picture into Google image, and I luckily stumbled upon the website that mentioned the interactive version among many other results.

Comment: The Red Stone mentioned in the table is a 2003 anime version (because it mentions Red Water), and in there it is another amplifier distinct from Philosopher's Stone.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thanks, I updated the answer.

Comment: Note that the 2003 anime diverges significantly from the manga which HA wrote. It is a bit of a stretch to attribute Red Stone to her, since it is not actually present in the material that she wrote. As a rule of thumb, *Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood* (2008) is the more faithful adaptation, so if something is present in the 2003 anime but absent from *Brotherhood*, HA probably didn't create it.